# What are the IMAP folder called in a certain locale in Microsoft's Outlook 365 email account?

Tags: imap, outlook-365

I want to find out what the special IMAP folder are called in a specific locale in order to set up my email client properly.

By special folders I mean:

- Sent items
- Drafts
- Trash

Is there a documentation of Microsoft stating how they are called for a specific language? Are there default values? Or is this something that the admin has to setup?

I am mostly interested in what they are called in German, yet this question is not limited to this case.